# extraneous key [context] is not permitted in circleCI?

Tags: circleci

I am getting below error on CircleCI page as I am totally new to it. And I have to make it working. Let me know what would be solution to fix this issue.

Config.yml

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  slack: circleci/slack@3.4.2
  

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk
        environment:
             TZ: "Asia/Kolkata"
            
    working_directory: ~/repo
    environment:
         TZ: "Asia/Kolkata"
            
    steps:
      - checkout    
      - setup_remote_docker
      - restore_cache:
          key: circleci-java-spring-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
      
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: circleci-java-spring-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
      
      - store_test_results:
          path: target/surefire-reports
      
      - store_artifacts:
          path: target/demo-java-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}


      - run: 
          name: run tests
          command: mvn clean test -DTestNGFileName="./src/main/java/com /ios /testrunner/ iOS_Test_Runner.xml"
 
      - store_test_results:
          path: ./src/main/resources/reports
      - store_artifacts:
          path: ./src/main/resources/reports
     
      - run:
          name: Set git Commit Message
          command: |
            echo 'export GIT_COMMIT_DESC=$(git log --format=oneline -n 1 $CIRCLE_SHA1)' >> $BASH_ENV
            source $BASH_ENV

      - run:
          name: Get artifacts
          when: always
          command: |
            artifacts=$(curl -X GET "https://circleci.com/api/v2/project/github/myworkspace/$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM/artifacts" \
            -H "Accept: application/json" \
            -u "$CIRCLECI_TOKEN:")

            echo "export ARTIFACT_RESPONSE=$artifacts" >> $BASH_ENV
            #ART=$(echo $artifacts | grep -Eo '(http|https)://output.circle-artifacts.com/*/*.html' )
            #echo "export ART_ALERT=$ART"
            
      - slack/status:
           fail_only: false
           failure_message: ':black_circle: *${CIRCLE_JOB}* Failed! Branch: *${CIRCLE_BRANCH}*, Started By: *${CIRCLE_USERNAME}*, Message: *${GIT_COMMIT_DESC}*'
           success_message: ':large_blue_circle: *${CIRCLE_JOB}* Succeeded! Branch: *${CIRCLE_BRANCH}*, Started By: *${CIRCLE_USERNAME}*, Message: *${GIT_COMMIT_DESC}*,REPORT_URL: ${ART_ALERT}'
           webhook: ${SLACK_WEBHOOK}
           
      - run:
          name: Download And Upload on Slack
          command: |
            echo "slack"
            download=$(curl -H "Circle-Token: $CIRCLECI_TOKEN" https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/myworkspace/latest/artifacts)
            curl -F file=@./src/main/resources/reports/iOS_Automation_Report.html -F channels=$SLACK_CHANNEL -F token=$SLACK_API_TOKEN -F title="${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME} | branch -> ${CIRCLE_BRANCH} | commit -> ${GIT_COMMIT_DESC}"  https://slack.com/api/files.upload

      - run:
          name: Download And Upload on Slack
          command: |
            echo "slack"
            download=$(curl -H "Circle-Token: $CIRCLECI_TOKEN" https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/myworkspace/latest/artifacts)
            curl --insecure -F file=@./src/main/resources/reports/iOS_Automation_Report.html -F channels=$SLACK_CHANNEL -F token=$SLACK_BOT_TOKEN -F title="${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME} | branch -> ${CIRCLE_BRANCH} | commit -> ${GIT_COMMIT_DESC}"  https://slack.com/api/files.upload

workflows:
  runtest:
    jobs:
      - build:
          context: 
            - shared-circleci-token
```

Error log:

```
ERROR IN CONFIG FILE:
[#/jobs/build] 0 subschemas matched instead of one
1. [#/jobs/build] only 1 subschema matches out of 2
|   1. [#/jobs/build] extraneous key [context] is not permitted
|   |   Permitted keys:
|   |     - description
|   |     - parallelism
|   |     - macos
|   |     - resource_class
|   |     - docker
|   |     - steps
|   |     - working_directory
|   |     - circleci_ip_ranges
|   |     - machine
|   |     - environment
|   |     - executor
|   |     - shell
|   |     - parameters
|   |   Passed keys:
|   |     - docker
|   |     - context
|   |     - working_directory
|   |     - environment
|   |     - steps
2. [#/jobs/build] expected type: String, found: Mapping
|   Job may be a string reference to another job
```